# Google Chrome Hijacking to www1 Antivirus downloading website

Tags: spyware

Every so often, spontaneously without warning, my Google Chrome has been redirecting to this type of website

**WARNING SPYWARE LINK***

```
http://www1.analys-thread.com/?p=p52dcWptaF/Cj8bYbnx9d3le0KCfZlbVoKDb2YegparGh8WilnGbk3ucqqjOkorapZxqZGObmF2YYWKZZpeK1qWYpqvYnpNflZd2iYtaqXbTksrbpJVYp5qn1FjZkZyTmsTW11ynnpfY1cycXZaam2OanZ6Hoc3anZVqWqihyaSfVpbPmcihiaWqb2eXl5dpY2RubG5aoYDTnNnWbladiJulyWqTYmaaXZSUl2Jr
```

**WARNING***

I'm not sure why nor is any of my usual AV/Spyware system is detecting it.  The Domain URL keeps changing but it's still the same site where it wants me to download an exe.

Answer (score 1):

My advice: wipe the drive and do a clean install. You'll lose more time trying to fix it with the risk of not fixing it than it will take you to do the install.

If you persist that you can't, change your default browser to Firefox or Opera. If it keeps occuring, then at least it's not Chrome related...

But it sounds like a malware infection, in which case I don't think there are real solutions if you can't "detect" it.

Comment: There should just be a sticky question/answer: wtf to do when I get a virus?!?

Comment: True that the "cleaning from virus" or "cleaning from spyware/malwares" is coming back often. We should probably make a wiki question, which would contain the good answers, good procedures (and which could be updated easily). We would be able to refer to that in all other virus situations. I'll probably do that, one of these days (unless someone else does it first). Wondering as well about creating such "wiki" questions for plenty others, hmm... We'll think about that in next days, I think.